# How make changing to the /etc/hosts file take effect?

Tags: hosts

I added some lines to my `/etc/hosts` file to resolve a private hostname, but every time after rebooting, the lines I added get lost. Should there be any setting options to make these changes take effect?

Comment: Do you edit it from root?

Comment: @Daniil yes, of course

Comment: Are you using some third-party VPN client. Some "disfunctional" clients modify the /etc/hosts files themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client is known to show this behavior. It will reset your `/etc/hosts` file on reboot to the contents of `/etc/hosts.ac`.

If you use this VPN client, you should make your modifications to both files.

See this hint for more info.

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20111011050950471

Comment: god, i really use Cisco AnyConnect VPN...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some app deletes this lines from `/etc/hosts` on system startup. OS X itself doesn't delete any lines on startup nor reboot.

Comment: And my estimated guess would be a third party VPN client.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the hosts file, change the permissions on it to stop the file being modified. You may have to play a bit to see what works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts` in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [pulse secure](https://www.pulsesecure.net/) the file `/private/etc/jnpr-pulse-hosts.bak` gets copied to `/private/etc/hosts` every time you reconnect to the VPN (including each time your Mac wakes up from sleep mode).

So if you want some changes to survive a reconnection, edit the `/private/etc/jnpr-pulse-hosts.bak` file, use

```
sudo vi /private/etc/jnpr-pulse-hosts.bak
```

to add your changes there.

Then disconnect the network and reconnect (use the option disconnect in `pulse secure` or pull the network cable off and on or disable and re-enable the wifi) and once pulse secure reconnected to your VPN, check that your changes are now in `/private/etc/hosts`.